# UnsupportedOperationException vs Interface Segregation

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, solid

This is a follow up/related question to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72997578/interface-segregation-avoid-typecasting/73182378#73182378) I asked regarding Interface Segregation. I'll build up on the same example, providing a bit more context.

In the game I'm developing, a card is structured in the following manner:

- A card **must** have a primary ability
- A card **may** have an "ally" ability. If it does, it can be triggered, given a certain condition is satisfied. Actual condition is not relevant to the discussion.
- A card **may** have a "sacrifice" ability. If it does, it can be sacrificed, removing it from play, to trigger this ability.

Note that a card may have none, one, or both, of the optional abilities, it is not limited to just one.

My initial design was to have one single `Card` interface, with the following methods:

```
public interface Card {

  /* other relevant methods snipped */
  
  void useAllyAbility(GameContext context);

  void useSacrificeAbility(GameContext context);
}
```

However, since not every card is going to have the corresponding abilities, I realised I would have to throw something along the lines of `UnsupportedOperationException` in the cases where a `Card`'s `useXxxAbility` is called, but that card does not have the required ability. In practice, this should rarely happen, of course, since the game's UI client would not allow it, but it has to be implemented nevertheless.

My other approach was to separate the two methods in different interfaces, like so:

```
public interface Card {

  /* other required Card behavior */
}

public interface Sacrificable extends Card {

  void useSacrificeAbility(GameContext context);
}

public interface Allyable extends Card {

  void useAllyableAbility(GameContext context);
}
```

For reference, the `Player` interface that would end up invoking these cards would be:

```
public interface Player {

  void useSacrificeAbility(Sacrificable card, GameContext context);

  void useAllyAbility(Allyable card, GameContext context);
}
```

Where the `Player` implementation would ensure that the card is indeed playable (along with any other validations/restrictions). During initialization, depending on the card data, I would instantiate the correct class, and add it to a generic `Collection<Card>` (or domain-specific wrapping class). The UI Layer would then be responsible for casting the card into a more specific type based on user input.

Implementation-wise, however, I found this second approach to be much more complex than I initially thought. Some context here. Since it would be impractical to have a separate class for every single card in the game, I broke it up into the following hierarchy:

```
class AbstractCard implements Card {}

class SacrificableCard implements Sacrificable {

  public SacrificableCard(Card card, CardAbility sacrificeAbility) {}
}

class AllyableCard implements Allyable {

  public AllyableCard(Card card, CardAbiltiy allyAbility) {}
}
```

With a few more classes in between, which are irrelevant for the discussion at the moment (Like the linked question suggested, there are `ItemCard` and `ChampionCard` etc.). My main problem is how to implement a card that is both `Sacrificable` and `Allyable`. Would I need a new class, `SacrificableAllyableCard`? I figured this would get out of hand quickly if, somewhere down the line, I happen to need a third such interface, for example, `Comboable`. Then I would need additional classes for every single possible combination of interfaces.

I read about the `Bridge` pattern, which attempts to solve a similar problem, but I do not know how to apply it to this scenario, since I am adding new behaviour in each interface.

My only other thought was to use `DynamicProxy`, so that `SacrificableCard` and `AllyableCard` could wrap any type of `Card`, instead of the generic `Card`. But I fear this may complicate the code even more than just simply having both of these methods declared in the `Card` interface, which was the initial design.

My question(s), then, are the following:

- Does "Interface Segregation" make sense in this case? Since the "client" of this interface expects to work with `Card`s, is there any benefit to separating the interfaces for `Sacrificable`/`Allyable`?
- If everything is implemented in 1 interface, and I throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, does that violate LSP? My reasoning is that, even though both `AllyableCard` and `SacrificableCard` both implement the same interface, they would not be interchangeable with each other, since a `SacrificableCard` may not support `useAllyAbility`, which would result in a thrown exception.
- Are dynamic proxies a "bigger" evil than simply declaring 1 wide interface?
- What other approach would be recommended in this scenario?

Comment: What is `CardAbiltiy`? You might be on the right track there.

Comment: "*the game's UI client would not allow it*" - how would that work? How does the UI client know whether a card has an ability or not?

Comment: `CardAbility` is an interface/abstract class (haven't made the final decision yet) that represents an ability a card might have. For example, `DrawCardsAbility`, `GainHealthAbility` would be concrete implementations

Comment: "How does the UI client know whether a card has an ability or not?" My initial idea was to separate the UI and the core gameplay layer. So, the gameplay layer would expose its state via events, for example `record CardDrawnEvent(String name, CardAbility primaryAbiltiy, CardAbility sacrificeAbility, CardAbiltiy allyAbility)`. The client would use the data from these events to build up its own classes/state, and add whatever validations might be helpful, or convenient for a user.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is typically a bad idea to have “optional” methods in an interface that throw an exception when invoked. Yes, the Java standard library happens to do this, but this is widely considered to have been a mistake. Thus, your distinction between `Card`/`Allyable`/`Sacrificable` interfaces is much better. Now, consumers can inspect the card via `instanceof` to see which operations it supports.

But I think you are improperly requiring the creation of distinct classes for each combination of abilities. This is even an issue you raise yourself:

> it would be impractical to have a separate class for every single card in the game

Let's return back to the initial description of your scenario:

> - A card **must** have a primary ability
> - A card **may** have an "ally" ability. If it does, it can be triggered, given a certain condition is satisfied. Actual condition is not relevant to the discussion.
> - A card **may** have a "sacrifice" ability. If it does, it can be sacrificed, removing it from play, to trigger this ability.

I'm not a fan of the style of object-oriented analysis where we look at nouns and verbs in a requirements document, but here it is actually helpful!

You say that there are *cards* and *abilities*. These are nouns, so candidates for classes. A card *has* a primary ability. A card *has* zero or one ally abilities and sacrifice abilities. You have not used any verbs that would suggest that the card has any methods/behaviours, aside from getters. At first approximation, this would suggest something like the following class structure:

```java
class Ability {}

class Card {
  public Ability primaryAbility;
  public Optional<Ability> allyAbility;
  public Optional<Ability> sacrificialAbility;
}
```

Of course, the different ability types might be represented by different interfaces or classes if they differ in their behaviour.

Note that turning abilities from methods into independent objects and having a single class for cards gives us a lot of flexibility.

- We can create new cards at run time, without having to create custom classes. In particular, we can specify cards in configuration files.
- We can very easily inspect a card to see which abilities it supports. For example, a user interface might contain code like:

  ```java
  for (Card c in cards) {
    addButton("play card", c.getPrimaryAbility());

    c.getAllyAbility()
     .ifPresent(ability -> addButton("assist allies", ability));

    c.getSacrificialAbility()
     .ifPresent(ability -> addButton("sacrifice card", ability));
  }
  ```

It is quite normal in games to have entities that have multiple behaviours that cannot be easily squeezed into a fixed class hierarchy, so the idea to represent abilities as objects is quite common. This tends to enable more complicated game mechanics. Related ideas and patterns:

- Eric Lippert has a [blog post series about “Wizards and Warriors”](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) that starts with a typical class design for an RPG game (e.g. `class Staff extends Weapon`, `class Wizard { public Staff weapon; }`). However, it gets really hard to encode complex game mechanics into the code, for example dual-classing, or special interactions between items. [Lippert eventually concludes](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/) (emphasis in original):

  > **The fundamental problem is my initial assumption that the business rules of the system are to be expressed by writing code inside methods associated with classes in the business domain** — the wizards and daggers and vampires. We keep on talking about “rules”, and so apparently the business domain of this program includes something called a “rule”, and those rules interact with all the other objects in the business domain. So then should “rule” be a class? I don’t see why not! It is what the program is fundamentally about. It seems likely that there could be hundreds or thousands of these rules, and that they could change over time, so it seems reasonable to encode them as classes.

  Here, my proposed Ability class would be a bit like Lippert's Rule classes.
- A related idea from Nystrom's book *Game Programming Patterns* is the [*type object pattern*](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/type-object.html) – turning “is-a” relationships between classes (inheritance) into “has” relationships (composition).
- A couple of years back I wrote a [related answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359548) about representing game items that have overlapping but distinct capabilities. Similar to here, I suggested avoiding the creation of class hierarchies, and instead recommended creating adapter objects for when an object must be used through a particular interface. In your scenario, we might want to use a Card through its Sacrifice interface, which may be mediated by an appropriate Ability implementation. Core parts of the answer:

  > Some concepts like conceptual hierarchies of real-world objects map very badly into object oriented models. Thoughts like “A gun is a weapon, and a sword is a weapon, therefore I'll have a `Weapon` base class from which `Gun` and `Sword` inherit” are misleading: real-word is-a relationships do not imply such a relationship in our model. […] A base class is not a place to factor out the *common* parts of multiple classes.
  >
  > It is not necessary to create a hierarchy. The two types `Gun` and `Sword` may be entirely unrelated. Whereas a `Gun` can `fire()` and `reload()` a `Sword` may only `strike()`. If you need to manage these objects polymorphically, you can use the Adapter Pattern to capture the relevant aspects. […]
  >
  > Instead of trying to figure out a class hierarchy for that mess, it is better to have a class that provides slots for various capabilities. These slots can be changed at runtime. Each slot would be a strategy/callback like `OnDamageReceived` or `Attack`. With your weapons, we may have `MeleeAttack`,  `RangedAttack`, and `Reload` slots. These slots may be empty, in which case the object does not provide this capability. The slots are then called conditionally: `if (item.attack != null) item.attack.perform()`.

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example of how to use "a `Card` through its `Sacrificable`" interface? Because, if I understood the last part of your answer, and if `Card` has an accessible property `sacrificeAbility`, then there is almost no need for `useSacrificeAbility`, since a caller could simply `card.sacrificeAbility.ifPresent(ability -> ability.apply())`

Comment: Having methods report UnsupportedOperationException *without offering any way of querying for support* is a mistake.  On the other hand, there are many situations where it will be possible to use some means to perform some task on all objects that implement a certain interface, but for some implementations other means might be better.  Further, especially with wrapper objects, there may be situations where some instances of a type will support a feature but others will not.  Trying to encode everything in the type system will make such situations awkward.

Comment: Perfect! I came here to post basically this, but you've already said everything I would've wanted to say, and quite eloquently as well.

Comment: @StefanRendevski Correct, a `useSomeAbility()` method would be inappropriate, though perhaps there could be convenience methods like `useSomeAbilityIfItExists()` or `hasSomeAbility()`. Depending on the specific design, it is not necessary to store Abilities in fields. They could also be created on the fly in getter methods. Let's assume that Card is an interface, not a class. If we have a custom `Card` implementation, the returned Ability might just call back into the card implementation – an example of an adapter. But this is incompatible with the “slots” design.

Comment: @amon Currently, `CardAbility` is a functional interface, with an `apply(GameContext)` signature. `GameContext` contains a reference to the card that invoked the ability. So, yes, `Ability` instances can be created on the fly. The reason I chose to have `useSomeAbility()` method, was because of state. A certain ability can only be used once per turn. I placed this state management in `Card`, so that calling `Ability.apply()` directly would not update the state. Maybe I should reconsider, and either put state management in `Ability`, or have `Ability` call a method on `Card` to indicate change

Comment: @StefanRendevski That sounds like a lot of complexity. I'd wager the guess that state management should be the responsibility of neither the Ability nor the Card, though the Ability implementations would likely operate on the game state directly. I'd also have chosen a functional interface for Abilities, though this might make it difficult to introduce a “once per turn” constraint since abilities might not have a sufficient concept of identity. Perhaps you should track the history of all actions taken so far, and let abilities inspect that history?

Comment: @amon I decided to create a stateful `CardAbility` wrapper, as an inner class in `Card` , so that state management can be internal to the `Card` class, without the responsibility leaking into a specific `CardAbility` implementation. Reasoning being, a `CardAbility` may not know exactly how it is composed into a `Card`, i.e. a `CardAbility` does not know if it is the `primary`, `ally`, or `sacrifice` ability of a class, since it does not need to. From its point of view, its effect does not change based on this.

Comment: @StefanRendevski That sounds reasonable! Thanks for keeping me updated.

Answer (score 4):

> "However, since not every card is going to have the corresponding
> abilities, I realised I would have to throw something along the lines
> of UnsupportedOperationException"

You're thinking about it in the wrong way. As you outlined:

> - A card **must** have a primary ability
> - A card **may** have an "ally" ability. If it does, it can be triggered, given a certain condition is satisfied. Actual condition is not
>   relevant to the discussion.
> - A card **may** have a "sacrifice" ability. If it does, it can be sacrificed, removing it from play, to trigger this ability.

These statements, in their essence, do not describe an interface; these are really the *rules* of the game.
When a card doesn't have the "ally" ability or the "sacrifice" ability, it's not an exceptional circumstance - so you shouldn't treat it as such (i.e., you shouldn't throw an exception, except *maybe* at construction time).

Given this perspective, you have different options here - you could retain the same interface, and implement these optional abilities as no-ops (Null Object Pattern, or something along those lines). Or, you could introduce the Ability object, and just have your interface be something that returns a list of abilities, or maybe a list of abilities by category (where you'd return an empty list when there are no abilities in that category). You'd probably have to modify your surrounding logic to work with this new interface, but doing one of these things avoids conditionals and null checks, and makes your code cleaner and more readable (as in, if you do it right, you'll find the code easy to make sense of).

That said, I'm not really trying to suggest any particular solution here, I just want to steer your thinking in a different direction. You know what the gameplay should be, so you'll probably come up with better ideas than I can produce. It's worth going down that path just to sort of "explore the design space", even if you decide to backtrack.

Finally, it's not necessarily the best idea to model different kinds of cards as different *types* (subclasses). If you have the Ability class, then Card could just be one class, and different kinds of cards would be represented by different combinations of Abilities. In such a scenario, the abilities might form a type hierarchy instead. That's quite a bit more flexible (you yourself have noticed that it would be impractical to have a separate class for each kind of card), and it's likely to work better with an editor or game UI. You could do other cool things, e.g., you could have prototypical card instances that you load from a file (perhaps created in an editor), and clone them when you need new instances of that type to form decks and whatnot.

Comment: A reason why I opted for throwing an exception, or really, treating a missing "sacrifice" ability as exceptional, is because, in the context of a method such as `useSacrificeAbility`, a caller should expect that the card was sacrificed and is no longer in play. Throwing an exception seemed a much cleaner approach than returning a boolean to indicate whether or not the ability was in fact used. Moreover, invoking a `useSacrificeAbility` where none exists suggests a bug somewhere in the code base, since certain validations have obviously been forgotten, because such an invocation mustn't happen

Comment: @StefanRendevski What I'm saying is you wouldn't have `useSacrificeAbility` at all (for example). Think through your game logic, and solve these problems in the implementation of the gameplay itself, not in the interface. Maybe you don't need to know the concrete ability at compile time. Just show available abilities to the user, and react to their click. If the card doesn't have a sacrifice ability, it's not going to be there for them to click. What I'm saying is you probably need to *reconceptualize* this, instead of trying to manipulate the compiler to do these checks, or throwing.

Comment: The game architecture is one of server-client, which will most likely be written in different languages altogether. A user would interact with the client, then the client would send the user input to the server for processing and updating of game state. The client would obviously check if an ability is present before presenting a button to the user, but a client is not always 100% reliable. A tech-savvy user could hijack the client to send faulty information to the server. The server then, would have to additionally validate user input, hence `useSacrificeAbility`.

Comment: @StefanRendevski - This doesn't make much difference (with respect to what I'm saying) - it's just a different delivery mechanism for the input. If you need to validate the input, you should do it in the boundary of your application. The Card and Ability types would get the the already validated input from their callers, and shouldn't be responsible for that. But even if you don't validate the input, if you have a Card represented by a list of abilities, a tech savvy user cannot invoke an ability that's not present on the instance. Your card would just do nothing.

Comment: But if the card does nothing, then we are back to my initial problem of knowing if a card was successfully sacrificed or not. Successfully sacrificed cards need to be removed from play, so this needs to be communicated somehow to the caller. In which case, I would then have to check the return value, and conditionally proceed with the remainder of the game logic for this scenario, something that I think can both lead to errors, and clutters the code unnecessarily. Instead, a much more elegant solution, in my view, would be to raise an exception, and, eventually, propagate this to the user.

Comment: In OOP methods are message handlers. Just because a card can't be sacrificed doesn't mean you can't tell it to sacrifice. This doesn't have to be a no-op. This could be a booming voice saying "illegal move". If you don't want the UI to show a sacrifice button then when you tell the card to create it's buttons have it not create that one.

Comment: One simple way to handle the Ability object is to make it an enum. Instead of `useAllyAbility(context)`, it would be `useAbility(Ability.ALLY, context)`, etc. That makes it easy to serialize, hides the implementation from the client, makes it relatively easy to add new abilities if you need them later, and presents a simple way to check for abilities (`Set<Ability> getAbilities()`). The big disadvantage is that the `useAbility` method needs to do its own dispatch. One way to do that is to maintain a `private Map<Ability, AbilityHandler>`, which powers both `getAbilities` and `useAbility`.

Comment: I thought that having a `Set<Ability>` might be a bit inconvenient to work with, considering the requirement that a card **must** have a primary ability, since now, at construction time, I would have to check the set to see if it contains an Ability of type `Ability.PRIMARY`.

Comment: I do not think there is need for `AbilityHandler`, because `Ability` itself implements an `apply()` method. The reason for `useAllyAbility`/`useSacrificeAbility` methods, instead of just calling `ability.apply()` directly, was, because of state. A card's ally/sacrifice ability can only be played once in a turn. So I made `Card` responsible for tracking this state. But maybe the better approach would have been to have `Ability` track its own state, and then I could have done `getAllyAbility().ifPresent(Ability::apply)`, like @FilipMilovanović suggested

Comment: @StefanRendevski - You're focusing on the wrong things; what I'm trying to say is, the fact that your current approach got you stuck and that you're here asking this question suggests that the approach you took, and the way you conceptualized things, *does not align well with what you're trying to do*. As in, it stands in your way. So you need some way to generate alternate ideas so that you can get unstuck. What I'm saying is, create, like, a git branch, and then go and try something *vastly different*, something unorthodox, even silly (not necessarily what I suggested, but *something*) 1/3

Comment: I can't really elaborate much more here, but Eric Lippert goes through a similar exercise on his blog; its a good read, if you have time - it's a 5-part series of articles ([1](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/), [2](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/30/wizards-and-warriors-part-two/), [3](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/04/wizards-and-warriors-part-three/), [4](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/07/wizards-and-warriors-part-four/), [5](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/)). 2/3

Comment: TLDR: He starts, like you (and like most people would), with the idea to use the type system to ensure the rules of the game at compile time, encounters difficulties, and, like you, resorts to runtime exceptions. He talks about how it's difficult to figure out how to invoke the right code, and to decide where to put that code. Then he goes on to elaborate on why this approach turns out to be fundamentally flawed for his scenario. The point is, the first design one comes up with is not necessarily workable; sometimes you have to rethink the whole thing. 3/3

Answer (score 3):

> Does "Interface Segregation" make sense in this case?

Probably not. If I got this right, `Sacrificable` and `Allyable` are properties which may or may not be available by a card type which is best configured dynamically at runtime. Hence I would not use inheritance to model their availability, since inheritance is a compile time approach.

For practical purposes, there should be boolean attributes `Sacrificable` and `Allyable` in your class which provide the information if `useSacrificeAbility` and `useAllyAbility` can be called safely.

> If everything is implemented in 1 interface, and I throw UnsupportedOperationException, does that violate LSP?

Not when the contract of those methods (which can be simply the informal documentation) says that a user has to expect this kind of exception. Moreover, it is not even clear to me if you really need a `Card` interface at all, or if Card might be a class with no further inheritance. If not, with no subtyping involved, there cannot be a LSP violation.

Comment: I am using composition over inheritance when it comes to `SacrificableCard` and `AllyableCard`, those classes being wrapper/decorator for an existing card. 

As for not needing interface/inheritance, is this with regards to the `Sacrificable`/`Allyable` interfaces, or `Card` in general? If it is the former, that is indeed my dilemma, whether or not those interfaces should exist. The only reason I added them was to avoid throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` in the case where a client tries to use an ability that does not exist.

Comment: In my initial design, there were indeed methods like this one: `Optional<CardAbiltiy> getSacrificeAbility`, which indicated an absence of such an ability.

Comment: @StefanRendevski: see my edit (but actually it does not matter: even with Card being an interface, there will be no LSP violation).

Answer (score 1):

> game's UI client would not allow it

How would the UI know that? It is a design smell for something external to know the capabilities of an object "better" than the object itself. More on this below.

> The UI Layer would then be responsible for casting the card

Aside from doing casting, which in itself is a smell, the UI layer again seems to know something that the object should only know.

So let's say this is something the `Card` should know. What if instead of having methods for every capability only for the UI then to call if selected, there were only one method where the `Card` can present itself and it simply "add" the necessary options into the UI itself.

In this case the "UI" doesn't have to know what capabilities the card has, this responsibility can stay completely in the card object, where it (arguably) belongs. The UI will just stay the UI, only responsible for presenting options and then triggering the callback the `Card` specifies. It doesn't need to cast, nor know anything specific to a card so your problem would be solved.

Comment: The core game logic being encapsulated in `Card`, it would then expose its state to the game client. For the sake of discussion, the game client could receive an event, containing every property of the card, and there would be a UI component to instantiate an appropriate class, which class would then have certain validations. For the use case "trigger an ally ability", then, the game client would check if a card has an ally ability, or is of certain type, and not allow the action to continue. 

(contd)

Comment: server wise, the UI layer would have a certain handler for the command "useAllyAbility", or "useSacrificeAbility". It will retrieve the requested objects, and perform type casting. The only "knowledge", then, that the UI layer has, is that it needs an "Allyable" to satisfy a request for "useAllyAbility", which seems logical to me